# Which Connection Pool should I Use?

Tags: java, mysql, connection

I have web service designed for Mobile applications. This web service accesses the MySQL database.

There may be many users who runs the mobile app say 100000 concurrent.

I am very much in confusing that which Connection Pool should I use for MySQL database connectivity in JDBC. Please guys suggest me reliable, faster, easier and efficient connection pool to be used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *100,000* concurrent users? That sounds... *very* optimistic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100k concurrent mobile application users usually does not mean 100k concurrent database connections. In fact, that is almost never the case for a web service. The reason for having a pool is so that connections can be shared efficiently between users/sessions (or between multiple service requests to the database.)

Usually, the database connection pooling built-in to your application server is the easiest, and an often sufficient, solution.  In the case of Tomcat 6/7, that would be the newer "[Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html)".

Well-known standalone options included [Commons-DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) and [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). However, there have been issues with both libraries.  These days if you need a standalone connection pooling library, I would recommend trying the "[Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html)".